# How to check all versions of Python installed on OS X and CentOS

Tags: python, linux, macos, centos, version

I just started setting up a CentOS server today and noticed that the default version of Python on CentOS is set to 2.6.6. I want to use Python 2.7 instead. I googled around and found that 2.6.6 is used by system tools such as YUM so I should not tamper with it. Then I opened up a terminal on my Mac and found that I had Python 2.6.8 and 2.7.5 and 3.3.3 installed.

Sorry for the long story. In short I just want to know how to look up all the versions of Python installed on CentOS so I don't accidentally install it twice.

Comment: does centos have the `which` command, `which -a python`?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28288095/3001761

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use,

```
yum list installed
```

command to find the packages you installed.

Comment: It doesn't give the list of python installed in the system. SO want python versions, not the list of packages. The @gabriel answer is good according to me. You can also use "whereis python" . it also gives the list of python on my centos and Mac system.

Comment: In that case you can do `yum list installed | grep python`

Comment: Bro already has done. Now it is showing list python packages NOT list of python versions

Answer (score 170):

The more easy way its by executing the next command:

```
ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
```

Output look like this:

```
/usr/bin/python           /usr/bin/python2.7        /usr/bin/pythonw
/usr/bin/python-config    /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/pythonw2.7
```

Comment: This answer is not very specific, please edit it to clarify the intention.

Comment: This one did it for me. which python etc only give me the current version in use, not the other installed ones.

Comment: Careful, some could be installed in usr/local too. So run this too. ls -ls /usr/local/bin/python*

Comment: With this answer i can see all the python versions installed. works perfect ubuntu 17.04

Comment: For OSX users, python2.7 comes pre-installed in /usr/bin/ but any python versions that were downloaded and installed by a user are likely in /usr/local/bin/ (see OutOnAWeekend's comment).

Comment: This certainly did not give me the python 3.6.8 version installed on my system.

Comment: This would also miss anything in anaconda. To me, it sounds like the original question is how do you do this for your entire system, not just in usr/bin

Comment: Why is this comment favored above the one recommending "whereis python"?  The whereis will provide far more details and is the standard for finding executable files installed on your system.

Comment: What are the `-ls` flags intended to do in this case? The output looks like a plain `ls` which should be sufficient in this case anyway.

Answer (score 31):

we can directly use this to see all the pythons installed both by current user and the root by the following: 
                                 `whereis python`

Answer (score 18):

Here is a cleaner way to show them (technically without symbolic links). This includes python2 and python3 installs:

```
ls -1 /usr/bin/python* | grep '.*[2-3]\(.[0-9]\+\)\?$'
```

Where `grep` filters the output of ls that that has that numeric pattern at the end ($).

Or using `find`:

```
find /usr/bin/python* ! -type l
```

Which shows all the different (`!`) of symbolic link type (`-type l`).

Answer (score 16):

Find out which version of Python is installed by issuing the command 
python --version:
    $ python --version
    Python 2.7.10

If you see something like this, Python 2.7 is your default version. You can also see if you have Python 3 installed:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.2
```

If you also want to know the path where it is installed, you can issue the command "which" with python and python3:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 7):

COMMAND: `python --version && python3 --version`

OUTPUT:

> Python 2.7.10 
>   Python 3.7.1

ALIAS COMMAND: `pyver`

OUTPUT:

> Python 2.7.10 
>   Python 3.7.1

You can make an alias like "pyver" in your .bashrc file or else using a text accelerator like AText maybe.

Comment: This assumes that the user knows they have python2.x and python3.x. What if they have anaconda and want to see those versions? This isn't general enough be be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

As someone mentioned in a comment, you can use `which python` if it is supported by CentOS. Another command that could work is `whereis python`. In the event neither of these work, you can start the Python interpreter, and it will show you the version, or you could look in `/usr/bin` for the Python files (python, python3 etc).

Comment: Best option for me on CentOS 7 -- I had another python 3.10 installed at `/usr/local` not `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 4):

```sh
compgen -c python | grep -P '^python\d'
```

This lists some other python things too, But hey, You can identify all python versions among them.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your default version of python setup. You can query by Python Version:

```
python3 --version //to check which version of python3 is installed on your computer
python2 --version // to check which version of python2 is installed on your computer
python --version // it shows your default Python installed version.
```

Answer (score 3):

To find what versions of python are installed use a `whereis` command.

```
$ whereis python | tr ' ' '\n' | grep ^/ | sort
```

this will show not only system versions installed in `/usr` directory but also versions installed by `pyenv` tool.

```
/etc/python2.7
/etc/python3.10
/etc/python3.8
/etc/python3.9
/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python
/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3.11
/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3.11-config
/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3.9
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10-config
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8-config
/usr/bin/python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.9-config
/usr/include/python3.10
/usr/include/python3.8
/usr/include/python3.9
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python3.10
/usr/lib/python3.8
/usr/lib/python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6m
/usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python3.10
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.8
/usr/local/lib/python3.9
/usr/share/info/python3.9
/usr/share/python
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python* & ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

Answer (score 1):

Sift through the output of this script.

```
sudo find / -name 'python*' -type f  -exec du -h {}  + | sort -r -h ~/Documents/python_locations.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to @nurealam siddiq answer,

```
python --version // it shows your default Python installed version.

python2 --version // to check which version of python2 is installed 

python3 --version //to check which version of python3 is installed 

python3.X --version // to further check which python3.X is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

To check python versions installed in your OS you can run the below commands:-

```
python2 -version
python3 -version
```