# How to know which --python interpreters are available for virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) allows you to set a specific Python version to use, e.g.:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.8 venv
```

I guess that virtualenv takes the selected Python interpreter for the system where it runs so you cannot put whatever you want as value for `--python` setting.

However, is there any way to know *a priori* which interpreters you have available (i.e. which values you can use for `--python`)? Something like `virtualenv --list-interpreters` (I have had a look in `virtualenv --help` but I haven't found anything like that).

Comment: Not really, because you could have valid interpreters anywhere. Depending on your platform/shell you may be able to list all executables starting with `python` in your path (using `zsh` on macOS I just type "python" and hit Tab twice), but that's potentially not exhaustive (e.g. I see `python3` and `python3.9` that way, but not the `python3.10` in Homebrew's cellar).

Comment: Can this question help you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30464980/11100417)

Comment: @jonrsharpe so basically, if I understand correctly, what `--python` does is a "bypass" of the interpreters found at OS level, right?

Comment: It's basically "what should `<virtualenv>/bin/python` be a symlink to"?